# SQL Server evaluation edition - won't start

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have not used this database for half a year and I've built an app on it and I need to use it now.

Now the database won't start using SQL Server Configuration Manager -  I guess it ran out of its evaluation period? So what now?

I thought about "upgrading" it to the Developer edition, but when upgrading the database do not show up in instance selection (I need the MSSQLSERVER01).

Is there a relatively easy way to solve this? Since I can't go to the database to backup and restore on different database

[image: screenshot from installation]

Comment: Evaluation licences last for 6 months; if you haven't used it for 6 months it's licence will be revoked.

Comment: yeah, it could be 6 months...I'm not sure though, but I'm looking for solution to this ... Is there a way to extract the data? There is only one table and its not that big too

Comment: You could attach the database to an express instance of the same version. Get the data, and then uninstall the 2 instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the system date, start evaluation edition, run the upgrade to developer edition:

Open `cmd`, type date, assign a date in the past (within the evaluation period)...keep doing that for a few times till the evaluation SQL Server is started (you might need to do that while "upgrading" to developer too).